# Pythontex - Unable to import .py files

Tags: import, pythontex

I am using pythontex to execute python code in latex. Since I have a large python code, I am trying to import the code using pycode ("\pyc{import code}"). The latex and python codes compile fine, but no sensible output is produced.

A minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}
\pyc{import test}
\end{document}
```

Note that, test is a python file ("test.py"), which has the following content:

```
print("hi")
```

Any suggestion on this would be highly helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That works just fine here, after `pdflatex` - `pythontex` - `pdflatex` I get a PDF with `hi`.

Comment: Torbjorn, that worked on another machine (linux plataform) for me too, but I haven't still figured out where the issue is. Did you get it working on a Windows OS ?

Comment: No, Linux. By the way, does "no sensible output" mean "no output at all", or do you get some output, only it isn't sensible?

Comment: The output.pdf does not contain imported python code, whereas everything outside the imported python code is printed correctly.

Comment: Code? It's not supposed to print the code. The manual says of `\pyc`: "`\pyc[<session>]<openingdelim><code><closing delim>`  This command is used for executing but not typesetting *`<code>`*. The suffix `c`
is an abbreviation of `code`. If the `print` statement/function is used within *`<code>`*, printed content will be included automatically so long as the package `autoprint` option is set to true (the default setting)."

Comment: I meant the output of the code, which in this case is "hi", but I am getting nothing. Whereas, everything is fine in linux.

Comment: Well, I don't have any good ideas. You could try adding `autoprint=true` as a package option, but as that is supposed to be the default, it's unlikely to help.

Comment: Upgrading the texlive package to 2017 didn't help. Perhaps reinstalling Anaconda will help. Anyway, thanks a lot for your comments Torbjorn.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by a file name conflict. In this case, both the .tex file and the .py file have the same name (which is "test"). Renaming either one of them will solve the issue.

It is interesting to note that, only the Windows OS has this issue; everything runs fine in Linux, even if the file names are the same.

Comment: Good to know, I was about to do the same thing and happened to stumble upon this question!

Comment: JiyuuSensei, nice to hear that this answer helped you. Also make sure that you are assigning path variables correctly. Seems like python and tex do not blend well in Windows OS (by default).